# link multiple MS project to Access/Excel

Tags: database-design, ms-access, database-link

sir 
I have a large project tracking database used to track PMs, status, help needed, action items, reports etc. I keep the project schedule in a large MS-Project file. I've exhausted all efforts to have my organization invest in an MS-Project server. How can I use the data found in my project file: Task Name, Resource, Start Date, End Date... etc as source data into my access database. Can these files be linked somehow if I put the project ID# into my project file as a foreign key? I just need to make the data available to people other than the PM. Ideas?

how can multiple MS project file can be view in one ms access or excel or any other application

Comment: Select cells in Microsoft Project >> Open Excel Paste special >> Paste link functionality and select As "Text", if that's kinda functionality you are after try checking this link out https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_project-mso_other/connections-between-ms-project-and-ms-accessexcel/0221ac39-527a-4a4c-9b16-2f60a00631fa

Comment: There is **Microsoft Project Oledb provider** available as well which you can use to connect to your project **.mpp** file from within Access or Excel.